# Compare the effect of centering power series about different points

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I loosely understand what it means to center a power series about a certain point. If you were to find a sufficiently high degree power series approximation to a function, would that not provide an approximation for all points in the domain? If so, why choose a particular point to center around?

Comment: Are you familiar with "interval of convergence" and the fact that a power series does not converge outside its interval of convergence?  (In the complex variables setting, replace "interval of convergence" with "disk of convergence".)  So a power series need not converge everywhere.  Further expanding a function at two different points may give two intervals of convergence that may, but need not, have any points in common.  Example of no overlap: power series of $\tan x$ expanded at $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$.  Example of partial overlap: $\tan x$ expanded at $-\pi/3$ and at $\pi/3$.

Comment: Yes reviewing the interval of convergence has helped clear up the confusion. I know now that value of a point of the approximation polynomial must be equal to that of the function to be approximated. Thank you for pointing this out.